# Winform display issue in citrix

Tags: wpf, citrix, winforms-interop

I am hosting a Winform control in WPF using `WindowsFormsHost` and when this application is launched in Citrix environment, Winform UI is displayed blue in color as shown in the below image:
[image: Winform displayed in Citrix]

Nothing is clean in the above image. 
I am already using below setting in WPF application but it is not fixing this issue.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles()
```

Any advice on how to fix this will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue used to come because of change in Windows theme from Windows7 to Windows classic. The winform control back color set was `System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption.` This color itself changes to dark blue as shown in the above image when theme is changed to Windows classic. To fix this i changed to back color of the winform control itself.